# Is it possible to develop wp7.5 (mango) applications with java?

Tags: java, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to develop wp7.5 (mango) applications with Java? What I know for wp7 during it launch is it temporary don't have any java runtime for wp7. How about now?

Thank you.

Comment: No, there is no JVM implementation that can run on Windows Phone

Comment: @Praetorian should've posted this as the answer! Probably won't ever be java available.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your choices for developing Windows Phone 7 applications at the present time are C# and VB. There is a reasonable degree of similarity of language features (syntax and semantics) between C# and Java, most people are able to make the transition between the two relatively easy.It's not trivial, but pretty straightforward.

Much more important, however, is the library that backs up the language and determines what you can do and how you do it. In the case of Windows Phone 7 that library is Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 which is common across all languages (XAML, C#, and VB). I've had several Java developer be productive in their first day writing WP7 applications in C# and XAML.

Answer (score 1):

no.... but in addition to VB or C# you could use Phone Gap to write you WP7 app.  PhoneGap Apps are written html and Javascript but compiled into native apps.  The added benefit is cross platform support.

http://phonegap.com/

However as other poster says if you know Java you will be be able to get upto speed with c#